# How to add textfield in inside appbar action widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

When i am trying to add textfield in Appbar, inside action widget, its showing error like "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a81ba NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT", Have u guys anyone know how to add textfield in appbar, inside actions, please add,

When i am trying to add

```
             actions:[
            TextField()
               ],
```

The error is like

```
               ════════ Exception caught by rendering library 
                ═════════════════════════════════
        RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a81ba NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
          'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
     package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
      Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it some `width` (`height` is optional) like:

```
actions: [
  SizedBox(
    width: 50,
    child: TextField(),
  )
]
```